# Detect user revoked permission to my app FB API

Tags: android, facebook, api, logout

I've been developing on android for a while, this time I was trying to make a login with FB API, so I did it correctly, I can log in get username, email, and all its required information..

Now, my question is, there is a way to automatically detect if user removed permission to my app? I say automatically because I know I can make a Graph Request to know permissions of the user with my app, but what I want is to perform an auto- logout from my app if user removed permission.

I've seen this kind of functionality on Tinders app (yes the one to make dates, lol)

Thanks in advance for your answers or tips.

Comment: You query /me/permissions and if the permission is missing you rerequest that permission

Comment: @WizKid, thanks I know how to do it, but my question goes to make it automatically, something like a listener.

Comment: When the user logs in you do the me/permissions request.